# Can a subclass of UIButton trigger segues?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, segue, xcode-storyboard

Is it possible for a subclass of a UIButton to trigger a segue in storyboard?
The segue stop working as soon as I change the custom class of a button in storyboard.

I have UIPageViewController embedded in a ViewController inside a NavigationController. One of the ViewControllers in the PageController have a subclassed Button that should perform a segue in the NavigationController.

The Button subclass is as follows:
Every thing else is wired up in storyboard only

```
class MiniButton:UIButton{

var originalBackgroundColor:UIColor?
var originalTextColor:UIColor?

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    originalBackgroundColor = self.backgroundColor
    originalTextColor = self.titleColor(for: .normal)
    self.backgroundColor = MiniColor.miniYellow
    self.setTitleColor(MiniColor.white, for: .normal)
}

func backToOriginalColors(){
    self.backgroundColor = originalBackgroundColor
    self.setTitleColor(originalTextColor, for: .normal)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    backToOriginalColors()
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    backToOriginalColors()
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please post a bit more code and details how you did it

Comment: Sure it can. The issue is with your code. Please show it.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. I edited it. The majority of the work is in storyboard only.

Answer (score 0):

Calling **super** on your subclass' methods is 'super' important =(

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event) // <--------

    originalBackgroundColor = self.backgroundColor
    originalTextColor = self.titleColor(for: .normal)
    self.backgroundColor = MiniColor.miniYellow
    self.setTitleColor(MiniColor.white, for: .normal)
}
```